# Loop over list of partial variable names in R

Tags: r

I've got a dataset relating to a list of drugs, "alcohol", "cannabis", "tobacco", "mdma", "cocaine", "amphetamine", "lsd", etc.. in a data frame, `df`.

Each one has variable ever used (`ever_[drug]`), used in year (`year_[drug]`), used in last month (`mth_[drug]`), which are answered sequentially. One would only be asked about the latter time frame if you answer "yes" (i.e. 2) to the previous. In each case "no" is 1. I need to recode into one overall variable, say, `my_[drug]` with values 0 (never used), 1 (used, not in last year), 2 (in last year), 3 (in last month).

This works for just one:

```
my_cannabis <-  ifelse(ever_cannabis == 1, 0, 
                ifelse(year_cannabis == 1, 1,
                ifelse(mth_cannabis == 1, 2, 3)))
```

How can I loop over all the drug names and generate `my_[drug]` for each?

EDIT - with some data:

```
structure(list
(ever_cannabis = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), 
year_cannabis = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA), 
mth_cannabis = c(2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
ever_cocaine = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
year_cocaine = c(NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), 
mth_cocaine = c(NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

(not entirely sure I've done that right)

For reference, in Stata it would be:

```
foreach v in cannabis tobacco mdma cocaine amphetamine lsd {
    gen my_`v' = 0
    replace my_`v' = 1 if ever_`v' == 2
    replace my_`v' = 2 if year_`v' == 2
    replace my_`v' = 3 if mth_`v' == 2
    }
```

SOLVED IT:

```
list_drugs <- c( "cannabis", "tobacco", "mdma", "cocaine", "amphetamine", "methamphetamine", "lsd")

for(i in 1:length(list_drugs)) {
  cur_dn <- list(drugname = as.name(list_drugs[[i]]))
eval(parse(text = paste0("my_",cur_dn," <-  ifelse(ever_",cur_dn," == 1, 0,", 
                                "ifelse(year_",cur_dn," == 1, 1,", 
                                "ifelse(mth_",cur_dn," == 1, 2, 3)))")))
}
```

Comment: rehape your data to have the columns as one column then use factor levels. This will be quicker and easier

Comment: Can you provide a `dput()` of your data or a piece of your data? This can help knowing the structure. Once we know that, it's easier to reshape and recode

Comment: drugs<-c("alcohol", "cannabis", "tobacco", "mdma", "cocaine", "amphetamine", "lsd"); allcols<-NULL; 
for(drug in drugs){allcols<-rbind(allcols,rbind(paste("ever_",drug,sep=""),paste("year_",drug,sep=""),paste("mth_",drug,sep="")))}; 
View(allcols)

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if the following code is the thing you expect:

```
lst <- lapply(seq(ncol(df)/3), function(k) df[,3*k + (-2:0)])
r <- lapply(lst,function(x) apply(x, 1, function(v) {k <- which(as.vector(v)==1);ifelse(length(k)>0,k-1,3)}))
names(r) <- paste0("my_",unique(gsub(".*_(\\w+)","\\1",colnames(df))))
my_drug <- data.frame(r)
```

yielding:

```
> my_drug
   my_cannabis my_cocaine
1            3          0
2            3          3
3            3          0
4            1          0
5            3          0
6            0          0
7            2          1
8            1          0
9            1          1
10           1          0
11           1          0
12           0          0
```

Comment: Not quite. Added the equivalent code in Stata, if that helps.

Comment: @JackDC Sorry that I know nothing about `Stata`, but I guess what you described in the example `my_cannabis` (to find which is equal to `1`) and the conditions for `Stata` (to find which is equal to `2`) are different....am I right?